# Should I update the list of filtered items after a bulk item edit?

Tags: search, workflow, filter

Scenario as follow:

Step 1: Search for a list of items base on the search/filter type such as in the image below.
[image: Search/filter bar]

Step 2: UI returns a list of items that have Status Idle and Priority Low attribute.

Step 3: Select 1 or more items in the list and edit the selected items' status from idle to active and priority from low to high.

Question:
After the user edited those selected items' status and priority, the original search input is invalid because the status is no long idle and priority is no longer low. How should I update the filtered list such that it make sense?

Here's my thought about it:

1. Show updated value and render the search query value Status:"idle" and priority:"low" as greyed out so it indicate those values are now invalid. Notification letting user know that the selected items have changed from original value to new value. As well as highlight the items in a different color for 3 second and then fades out. Update the value field from original to new value in the UI.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the use case here: "As a user, I would like to search for idling and low priority items and update those matching criteria XYZ to status 'active' and priority 'high'." Now the question is, if XYZ is present on the screen or not.

If it is, user will be picking items according to XYZ criteria. Thus, if they stay on the screen with the different status than indicated by the filter - there is no problem. You can always see why it is there. However, if items start disappearing it might pose a problem as if you made a mistake you won't be able to correct it.

Another option, XYZ is not present on the screen. It means, user has a list of items to update which he received from somewhere outside of the system. Then they will be going item by item and updating the fields. In the end, most likely they will want to double check their work, e.g. go over items again and compare to their original list. Thus, items should stay.

In both cases, they need to see on a glance what has changed to double check their work and correct errors. So some kind of highlighting is greatly needed.

And of course, the list should update if user makes a refresh.

Comment: Yes, that's the use case.

During the bulk editing modal, the user will be able to see the items they have selected for double checking if they have selected the items they want to change.